# Wann und warum ging das Beugen von Namen verloren?

Tags: history, person-names, inflection

Beim Lesen von Literatur zu Goethe und Schiller fiel mir auf, dass deren Namen in manchen Texten mitgebeugt wurden, so wie wir das heute noch mit den Objekten machen.

Der Lautwandlungsprozess zum [Neuhochdeutschen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuhochdeutsch) war meines Wissens bereits abgeschlossen, daher stellt sich die Frage, wie und wann diese Eigenart verloren ging.

Zum Beispiel:

> **Goethe  an Schiller, 1. November 1794**
>
> Morgen frühe gegen 10 Uhr hoffe ich **mit Meyern** in Jena einzutreffen [...]
>
> <sup>[Quelle](http://www.wissen-im-netz.info/literatur/goethe/briefe/schiller/1/023.htm)</sup>

Besonders interessiert mich außerdem, nach welchen Regeln gebeugt wurde.

Comment: Kleine Abschweifung der Vollständigkeit halber: Teil der Anrede wird immer noch mitgebeugt, nähmlich der Titel. "Ich hoffe mit *Herrn* Meyer in Jena einzutreffen."

Comment: ja, das war mir klar, mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir nur eigentlich ich sollte doch den Nachnamen selbst auch beugen, daher die Frage ;)

Comment: Es wäre interessant zu wissen, worauf sich der Ausreißer (1820-30) von "Meyern", der hier ersichtlich ist, zurückzuführen ist: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Meyern&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3

Comment: Nach Adam Riese...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Vorab eine Präzisierung: Namen werden auch heute noch gebeugt, allerdings nur im Genitiv:

> Ich habe Müllers Kuh gekauft.
>   Goethes Briefe sind aufschlussreich.
>   Es liegt auf Direktor Meyers Schreibtisch.

Bei einigen Namen wird auch der Plural gebildet:

> "Alle Marias bitte aufstehen!"

Allerdings ist es wahr, dass z. B. im Dativ keine Kasusendungen mehr verwendet werden.

Dabei spielt die Tendenz des Deutschen, das Kasussystem immer mehr zu vereinfachen, eine Rolle. Das begann im frühen Mittelalter mit der [Endsilbenabschwächung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelhochdeutsch#Das_Mittelhochdeutsche_als_.C3.A4ltere_Sprachstufe_des_Deutschen). Endungen, die keine Funktion mehr haben, sind verschwunden, weil sie redundant sind.

Früher sagte man zum Beispiel *"im Hause"* oder *"mit dem Kinde"*. Auch das Genitiv-s bei Eigennamen mit Artikel wird immer häufiger weggelassen wie in *"die Malerei des Barock"*.

Zur Frage, wie die Eigennamen zu Goethes Zeiten dekliniert wurden, habe ich [hier](http://verben.texttheater.net/forum/index.php?topic=2506.0) diese schöne Tabelle gefunden:

```
Fälle         Nennender    Zeugender    Gebender    Klagender    Rufender
              (Nominativ)  (Genitiv)    (Dativ)     (Akkusativ)  (Vokativ)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Konsonant     -            -ens         -en         -en          -e
              Faust        Faustens     Fausten     Fausten      Fauste!
              Johann       Johannens    Johannen    Johannen     Johanne!
              Fritz        Fritzens     Fritzen     Fritzen      Fritze!
              Johannes     Johannesens  Johannesen  Johannesen   Johannese!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Auf -e        -            -ns          -n          -n           -
              Goethe       Goethens     Goethen     Goethen      Goethe!
              Margarete    Margaretens  Margareten  Margareten   Margarete!
```

Comment: Danke, dass da auch ein Beispiel mit einem Namen der auf s endet dabei ist. Die alten Formen bilden sich ja manchmal auf der Zunge, aber erscheinen einem nicht richtig. War dann also _Dorisens_ mal korrekt?

Comment: Toll toll was du hier alles hervorzauberst! Ich hoffe es kommt noch etwas aber du liegst grad sehr klar in Führung ;) Ich finde es gerade höchst interessant, dass mir beim Sprechen meiner Mephistopheles-Rolle niemals diese Deklinationsgewalt aufgefallen ist, wohl aber beim nachherigen Studieren des Schriftverkehrs. Da merke ich wie tief verankert die Deklination in meinem Sprachgefühl ist : o)

Comment: @splattne, bist Du sicher, daß die Beugungen von Joe, Maria und Otto im Dativ und Akkusativ jemals so gewesen sind? Wir haben lateinisch "Mariä Himmelfahrt" als Genitiv und dann sicher auch im Dativ, aber eben wegen Latein; noch nie gehört oder gelesen habe ich jedoch den Akkusativ "Marian", aber gut, es mag angehen. "Ottoe" (Dat.) und "Otton" (Akk.) kommen mir jedoch ganz künstlich vor.

Comment: @Lumi Ja, du hast vermutlich Recht. Ich werde die Zeilen inzwischen rausnehmen, bis ich die korrekten Formen gefunden habe.

Comment: "dem Otto": aus einem Buch von 1789: http://goo.gl/Dvq9e

Comment: "bei der Mariä" (1808): http://goo.gl/ro9j9

Comment: Sehr schön, dein Otto-Beispiel. Dort steht oben auf S.99: "Da wir eines Zugs unsers Otto nach Italien so eben erwähnt haben [...]", also Genitiv ohne "s" am Ende, und ich glaube, das ist immer so, wenn der Genitiv im Artikel (oder Possessivpronomen) ausgedrückt wird. "Es hatte nemlich unsern Otto, [Komma sic] der Pabst Johannes XV. (XVI.) dahin eingeladen [...]", Otto also auch hier unbeugsam. :-)

Comment: Aber wann und warum *ging* es denn jetzt verloren?

Comment: @Debilski Es gibt die sogenannte "Sprachökonomie", sprich eine Tendenz, Dinge, die aus irgendeinem Grund redundant sind, einfacher zu gestalten. (*"... Tendenz des Deutschen, das Kasussystem immer mehr zu vereinfachen, eine Rolle."*)

Comment: @splattne Stimmt, aber warum hat es zuallererst die Flexion von Eigennamen abgeschwächt. Diese ist doch eben gerade nicht redundant, da Eigennamen im Regelfall schließlich ohne Artikel, also ohne jeglichen Kasusmarker benutzt werden.

Comment: "Fritzens" hätte ich in der passenden Laune auch benutzt, um "Fritz'" zu vermeiden, aber mir war nicht klar, dass es einmal auch "Johannens" hieß.

Comment: Gibt es nicht auch noch den Plural am Nachnamen: _Wir waren mit Meiers Essen._ oder _bei Hempels unterm Sofa_ ?

Comment: "Marias Hund beißt den Hund der Maria." - Ich glaube nicht, dass es sich bei dem -s um eine Deklinationsendung handelt, denn "Hund der Marias" wäre eindeutig falsch, sogar misverständlich.

Comment: Die Quelle erscheint mir leider nicht sehr belastbar.

Comment: Die Beugung Weiblicher Vornamen ist nichts ungewöhnliches. In Erzählungen des 19. Jhds ist sie sehr verbreitet. Siehe etwa hier: http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Droste-Hülshoff,+Annette+von/Erzählungen/Ledwina Ledwina, Ledwinens, Ledwinen... Mein Onkel sprach so und auch ich kannte es als Kind gar nicht anders. Auch „Johannesens“ ist das, was ich als Kind selbstverständlich schrieb. „Fauste“ allerdings hätte ich als lateinischen Vokativ zu „Faustus“ verstanden.

Comment: Zum Vokativ, der mir als einziger ungewöhnlich erschien, habe ich inzwischen auch Belege gefunden. Gleich am Anfang von Grimms »Kinder- und Hausmärchen« steht: An die Frau Bettina von Arnim. Liebe Bettine, dieses Buch kehrt abermals bei Ihnen ein, wie eine ausgeflogene Taube die Heimat wieder sucht und sich da friedlich sonnt.